# Updating a quantity after every iteration in a for-loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am writing a for loop. I want to update `sigma=10` with `sigma` calculated in the next line for every `t`. I present the current and expected output.

For `t=0`, `sigma=10`, `sigma=0.5*10*(0-2)=-10`.

For `t=1`, instead of `sigma=10`, I want to have `sigma=-10` as calculated for `t=0`. Then `sigma=0.5*-10*(1-2)=5`

```
for t in range(0,2):
    sigma=10
    sigma=0.5*sigma*(t-2)
    print(sigma)
```

The current output is

```
-10
-5
```

The expected output is

```
-10
5
```

Comment: `0.5 * 10 * -1` will give `-5` only.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "The expected output is" Why? Please think carefully about the logic of the code. When the loop runs for the second time, what do you expect `0.5*sigma*(t-2)` to do? What do you expect will be the value of `(t-2)`? What do you expect will be the value of `sigma`? (Hint: Is `sigma = 10` inside the loop, or outside? Therefore, will it be set to `10` just once before the loop, or again at the beginning of each loop? Which of those things *should* happen? Why?)

Comment: Also: please do not use irrelevant tags. The question clearly has nothing to do with Numpy, as the code is simply doing a little arithmetic with individual numbers, not Numpy arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sigma initial must be out of the loop, here is the correct code:

```py
import numpy as np

sigma=10 
for t in range(0,2):
    sigma=0.5*sigma*(t-2)
    print(sigma)
```